# Use of \@argtabularcr doesn't match its definition

Tags: errors, titles, ieeetran

I got this error while compiling a document using the `IEEEcolor` document class from the [IEEE Author center](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/Alternate-Transactions-Articles-LaTeX-template.zip):

> Use of @argtabularcr doesn't match its definition. \subsection

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: please do not add an answer in the question posting, it makes a mess of the archived question/answer format of the site. It is perfectly Ok to asnwer your own question, but the answer part should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I had copied the title of the paper into the \markboth command with an included line break since my title was too long to fit on a single line:

```
\markboth{IEEE Journal of This and That}%
{Author \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: My paper title that is too long\\for a single line by one word only}
```

Removing the `\\` from the second `\markboth` argument fixed the issue

It was a bit tricky to find, since the compiler complained about the error a couple of pages into the document, at the point of the page break where the content of the second `\markboth` argument was to be used, while the offending command was near the beginning, before `\begin{document}`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Posted on behalf of OP.